# Open Source Software to speed up video?

Tags: video

Is there any open source software to load a .MOV video and speed it up? I've got some video of storms that I'd like to speed up 10x.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/) (well, mencoder) will do that.

Instead of re-posting I will direct you to the example at the [source](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.multimedia/browse_thread/thread/5aa9c6282cb9a741/bfffd8d910e0d9fb).

Comment: Hi, is mencoder like a video version of ImageMagick? Just a command-line utility to modify videos?

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 3):

If you mean increasing the playback speed, [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) can do that. VLC is an open source software for both Windows and Unix/Linux environments.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a speeded up version of the video (and not just for a single time playback) you will have to re-encode the video.  This is somewhat complicated but you can do it with a myriad of video encoding programs.  My favorite is VirtualDub http://www.virtualdub.org/.